# Opening saved connections when launching Service Bus Explorer

Tags: azureservicebus, service-bus-explorer

Is there a way to open all existing saved connections in Service Bus Explorer. I have saved connections but can't see an option to launch all Azure Service Bus Namespaces

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such option. Opening all saved connections is a bit of an edge case because often the number of connections could be significant and not needed all at the same time.

You can [raise an issue](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues) to ask for the feature and discuss validity of the use case. If the feature is important to you and you would like to contribute, send a PR to accomplish this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this tooling is really good, its only a few features off from being able to to use it for prod monitoring. For example, if all queues could be opened at startup, then notification configured on the system tray when particular selected DLQs occur, then we can use it to monitor all connections across our estate and alert developers when something goes wrong.